# Why doesn't deprecation warning disappear when verifying Build.VERSION.SDK_INT before using deprecated item?

Tags: android, android-studio

[THEME_HOLO_LIGHT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#THEME_HOLO_LIGHT) was deprecated in API 23.

So why do I still get a deprecation warning when verifying I'm using it on API < 23?

[image]

Relevant piece of my `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    useLibrary "org.apache.http.legacy"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
}
```

Comment: Please post your Gradle build settings or manifest. It's possibly caused by Android Studio

Comment: You know you already have handled that deprecation. So you may put `//noinspection deprecation` right above that statement.

Comment: @ozbek yeah I'm just confused because I thought I've seen this kind of check automatically hide the deprecation warning in the past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also experienced the same issue when using `targetSdkVersion` containing deprecated code. It seems that the `if` statement is ignored by `Lint` check. So, I have to suppress lint on that block to remove the warning.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that after passing `-Xlint:deprecation` option, I have hundreds of such warnings (but I never see any warnings without said option)