# I keep getting deprecated API warning even with correct check

Tags: android, android-studio, deprecated

I'm working on a Android project, and at some point in my code I need to get the device serial number.

In order to get it I used to use `Build.SERIAL` which has been deprecated since Android *O*. To avoid problems I started using `Build.getSerial()`, and created a little method that wraps up the OS version check:

```
private static String getSerial() throws SecurityException {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        return Build.SERIAL;
    }

    return Build.getSerial();
}
```

Note: I'm not checking for the permission `READ_PHONE_STATE` (required by the `getSerial()` method) to be granted because I'm doing it at the start and make sure I already have it **before** getting to this method.

The problem is that, no matter how I write down the Android OS check I keep getting the deprecated API warning.

I tried the following and for all possible versions I keep getting the warning on `Build.SERIAL`

```
private static String getSerial() throws SecurityException {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        return Build.getSerial();
    }
    return Build.SERIAL;
}

private static String getDeviceUDI() throws SecurityException {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        return Build.getSerial();
    } else {
        return Build.SERIAL;
    }
}

private static String getDeviceUDI() throws SecurityException {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        return Build.SERIAL;
    } else {
        return Build.getSerial();
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is alright. maybe you need to clean or invalidate and restart your studio again ?

Comment: update your android studio to latest version

Comment: @Umair I tried to clean the project, rebuild and even restart Android Studio but nothing worked so far.

Comment: @FredMaggiowski and the interesting thing is I copy/pasted your code in my AS and it's working fine not warning or error message :D

And in that case MatPag answer is right you will have to supress the warnings

Comment: @Umair sounds funny :| I guess the code is right and AS is still drunk from the weekend... I'm trying updating it as suggested by Rahul

Comment: @FredMaggiowski haha yeah android never fails to amaze you :P. Happy coding :)

Comment: I tried updating Android Studio to the latest version but still didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't deprecation warning disappear when verifying Build.VERSION.SDK\_INT before using deprecated item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35881522/why-doesnt-deprecation-warning-disappear-when-verifying-build-version-sdk-int-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
@SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private static String getSerial() throws SecurityException {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        return Build.SERIAL;
    }
    return Build.getSerial();
}
```

to hide all the incorrect warnings

Comment: suppressing is not the solution I believe, there is always the reason for any warning :)

Comment: OK, but I'd prefer to actually resolve the warning rather than mute it.

Comment: There are a lot of points inside AS where warnings or deprecations messages are not correct and even when you take all the actions to be safe they remain there. If you know what you are doing sometimes the only thing you can do is suppress them.

Comment: @MatPag ok, I understand your point :) Do you think there's something I might be missing? Or this is an example of those point where AS is failing is job?

Comment: Watching at your code I think you did everything right. I think this is one of the cases where AS is failing.

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to update AS as suggested in a comment above, if it doesn't work again I guess I'll go with suppression :|

Comment: I tried updating AS to v3.1.2 and faced some peculiar problems, after fixing them I've seen that nothing has changed. I kept my code and added `//noinspection deprecation` comment to disable inspection on the `Build.SERIAL`. I don't link suppressing warnings but I don't know what else I can do..

Comment: It's perfectly fine to suppress warnings if you understand why you're doing that.  For example if a method was deprecated in a particular sdk version and you use the correct method for the given version, then it just a compiler nuisance error and surpressing the warning is fine.  In Kotlin you can suppress the warning at the statement level. I think Java only allows it at the function level, which is not as precise as one might want.

Answer (score 3):

It's annoying but I've only found something like this to work:

```
@TargetApi(BUILD.VERSION_CODES.N)
private static String getDeprecatedSerial() {
    return BUILD.SERIAL;
}

private static String getSerial() throws SecurityException {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        return getDeprecatedSerial();
    }

    return Build.getSerial();
}
```

This way you don't get deprecation warnings about the API level for this API & you don't suppress all deprecation warnings.