# Geocoder - getFromLocation() deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, geocoding, deprecation-warning, android-tiramisu

I've received a message that this function (or it's constructor) has been deprecated. There's a new constructor of that function that accepts an additional parameter `'Geocoder.GeocodeListener listener'` but that new constructor requires an API Level 33 and above. What should I do for the lower API levels, what's the solution?

[image]

Comment: The warning is incorrect, that is the way to go on lower SDKs. You can just ignore it. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675122/i-keep-getting-deprecated-api-warning-even-with-correct-check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is deprecated in API level 33, I believe this is the only option for lower API levels.

Answer (score 13):

[The Official Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder) - Use **getFromLocation(double, double, int, android.location.Geocoder.GeocodeListener)** instead to avoid blocking a thread waiting for results.

Example:

```
//Variables
val local = Locale("en_us", "United States")
val geocoder = Geocoder(this, local)
val latitude = 18.185600
val longitude = 76.041702
val maxResult = 1


//Fetch address from location
geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,longitude,maxResult,object : Geocoder.GeocodeListener{
 override fun onGeocode(addresses: MutableList<Address>) {

    // code                      
 }
 override fun onError(errorMessage: String?) {
     super.onError(errorMessage)

 }

})
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the cleanest way to handle this deprecation is move getFromLocation into new extension function and add @Suppress("DEPRECATION") like this :

```
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
fun Geocoder.getAddress(
    latitude: Double,
    longitude: Double,
    address: (android.location.Address?) -> Unit
) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1) { address(it.firstOrNull()) }
        return
    }

    try {
        address(getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)?.firstOrNull())
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        //will catch if there is an internet problem
        address(null)
    }
}
```

And this is how to use :

```
    Geocoder(requireContext(), Locale("in"))
        .getAddress(latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude) { address: android.location.Address? ->
        if (address != null) {
            //do your logic
        }
    }
```

Comment: THis answer worked for me specifically the `try { } catch { }` because I didn't have internet

Answer (score 1):

I adapted @Eko Yulianto's code, in order to avoid having to expose a callback.

```kotlin
private suspend fun Geocoder.getAddress(
    latitude: Double,
    longitude: Double,
): Address? = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
            suspendCoroutine { cont ->
                getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1) {
                    cont.resume(it.firstOrNull())
                }
            }
        } else {
            suspendCoroutine { cont ->
                @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
                val address = getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1)?.firstOrNull()
                cont.resume(address)
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Timber.e(e)
        null
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! I had to emit a collection of results when iterating over multiple addresses to a flow, and this was the solution which worked really well for me!

Answer (score 0):

Method [`getFromLocationName`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String,%20int,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20android.location.Geocoder.GeocodeListener)) still exists, but now expects "bounding box" parameters `lowerLeftLatitude`, `lowerLeftLongitude`, `upperRightLatitude`, `upperRightLongitude`.
Setting the "bounding box" to the view boundary coordinates should work.

```
@SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "RedundantSuppression"})
...

Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(requireContext());
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
    geoCoder.getFromLocationName(
            geocode, maxResults,
            lowerLeftLatitude, lowerLeftLongitude,
            upperRightLatitude,upperRightLongitude,
            addresses -> {
                Address bestMatch = (addresses.isEmpty() ? null : addresses.get(0));
                updatePosition(item, bestMatch);
            });
} else {
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(geocode, maxResults);
        Address bestMatch = (addresses.isEmpty() ? null : addresses.get(0));
        updatePosition(item, bestMatch);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (mDebug) {Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());}
    }
}
```

Comment: The other method signature without bounding box parameters still exists:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder#getFromLocationName(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.location.Geocoder.GeocodeListener)

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue recently where I kept getting Java.IO.IOException: grpc failed.

What I did was move that Geocoder code to a Runnable class and execute that code as its own Thread like so:

```
GeocoderThread geocoderThread = new GeocoderThread(latitude, longitude, this);
Thread gcThread = new Thread(geocoderThread);
gcThread.start();
try{
    gcThread.join();
}
catch(InterruptedException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
city = geocoderThread.getCity();
```

And this is my Runnable class:

```
public class GeocoderThread implements Runnable{
    Geocoder geo;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    String city;
    public GeocoderThread(double lat, double lon, Context ctx) {
      latitude = lat;
      longitude = lon;
      geo = new Geocoder(ctx, Locale.getDefault());
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try
        {
             //deprecated, need to put this in a runnable thread
            List<Address> address = geo.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 2);
            if(address.size() > 0)
            {
                city = address.get(0).getLocality();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
}
```